# Upgrading XCode 6 GM to XCode 6.0.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, app-store

I want to upgrade my XCode 6 GM to XCode 6.0.1 However, I have a new version of my iOS app waiting for review by Apple. If I upgrade my XCode before Apple approves the app, would that mess up my certificate? Any suggestion much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app is already in the queue, upgrading Xcode should not impact your app.